# scroll wheel not working in Blender (eratic behaviour)

Tags: windows

I think this is a problem related to some microsoft update, but i'm asking her for help.
Because the answer her would help a lot more Blender users than just me.

System info windows 11 this started around half juli 2023
The eratic behviour (it zooms in and out) i notice on scrollbars in chrome.
I have no special driver in place just normal windows, normal mouse with 2 buttons and a clickable mousewheel in the middle. A month earlier i never had these problem so i suspect a microsoft update / setting change.

The system isa gamesystem 3080ti gpu, so might be part of a mulitmedia update or so but still there should be an option to go back to old behviour I hope

The mouse is a bluetooth mouse (and yes i changed batteries as well)

Its only the wheel part, clicking and moving works fine.

Comment: First suggestion would be to try another mouse.

Comment: I dont have another wireless mouse, though it happened just as microsoft released some gaming mouse update, i dont know how to disable / remove that update. And for the record its not a 1000hz gaming mouse, its a bleutooth normal logitec nothing fancy about it besides that its on bleutooth

Comment: If it happens on scrollbars in chrome as well as having problems with Blender it's obviously not a problem that we can advise on here as it sound as as if it's a Microsoft problem.

Comment: @John Eason, thats exactly what i said and why i posted it with "windows" cause this affects other Blender users as well, so if someone knows something about it all blender users can find an answer